# ReactiveMongo 0.20.12-Play28 crashing on Startup with a MatchError: Success exception

Tags: scala, reactivemongo, play-reactivemongo

ReactiveMongo Version (0.20.12-play28)MongoDB version (4.4.3)Operating System (Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS)JDK ( OpenJDK 1.8.x)Library Dependencies
Play v2.8.7

Expected Behavior
On starting Play Server, reactive mongo should establish a connection with Remote DB

Actual Behavior
On starting, I am gettnig this log output. Seems ReactiveMongo is trying to reconnect but clearly not able to.

```
2021-04-10 06:18:32,480 [WARN] from reactivemongo.api.MongoConnection in scala-execution-context-global-4004 - Connection option 'authSource' deprecated: use option 'authenticationDatabase'
2021-04-10 06:18:33,752 [WARN] from play.filters.headers.SecurityHeadersConfig in play-dev-mode-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-7 - play.filters.headers.contentSecurityPolicy is deprecated in 2.7.0. Please use play.filters.csp.CSPFilter instead.
2021-04-10 06:18:33,764 [INFO] from play.api.http.EnabledFilters in play-dev-mode-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-7 - Enabled Filters (see https://www.playframework.com/documentation/latest/Filters):

play.filters.headers.SecurityHeadersFilter play.filters.hosts.AllowedHostsFilter play.filters.cors.CORSFilter
2021-04-10 06:18:33,884 [INFO] from play.api.Play in play-dev-mode-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-7 - Application started (Dev) (no global state)
2021-04-10 06:18:36,753 [ERROR] from play.api.http.DefaultHttpErrorHandler in application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5 -

! @7jbilj3n2 - Internal server error, for (GET) [/v1/user/1b22dedd-dd09-4931-8d43-d420d3553321/] ->

play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$$anon$1: Execution exception[[MatchError: Success(Response(MessageHeader(922, 2514917, 3000, 1), Reply(8,0,0,1), ResponseInfo(33e44ce5))) (of class scala.util.Success)]]
at play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$.throwableToUsefulException(HttpErrorHandler.scala:359)
at play.api.http.DefaultHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:261)
at play.filters.cors.AbstractCORSPolicy$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(AbstractCORSPolicy.scala:128)
at play.filters.cors.AbstractCORSPolicy$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(AbstractCORSPolicy.scala:126)
at scala.concurrent.Future.$anonfun$recoverWith$1(Future.scala:417)
at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.$anonfun$transformWith$1(Promise.scala:41)
at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:64)
at play.api.libs.streams.Execution$trampoline$.execute(Execution.scala:70)
at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:72)
at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.$anonfun$tryComplete$1(Promise.scala:288)
at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.$anonfun$tryComplete$1$adapted(Promise.scala:288)
at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:288)
at scala.concurrent.Promise.complete(Promise.scala:53)
at scala.concurrent.Promise.complete$(Promise.scala:52)
at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.complete(Promise.scala:187)
at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.$anonfun$transform$1(Promise.scala:33)
at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:64)
at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$AbstractBatch.processBatch(BatchingExecutor.scala:56)
at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.$anonfun$run$1(BatchingExecutor.scala:93)
at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$.withBlockContext(BlockContext.scala:85)
at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.run(BatchingExecutor.scala:93)
at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:48)
at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator.scala:48)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:175)
Caused by: scala.MatchError: Success(Response(MessageHeader(922, 2514917, 3000, 1), Reply(8,0,0,1), ResponseInfo(33e44ce5))) (of class scala.util.Success)
at reactivemongo.api.RetryableFailure$.unapply(Failover.scala:155)
at reactivemongo.api.Failover2.$anonfun$send$14(Failover.scala:117)
at scala.concurrent.Future.$anonfun$flatMap$1(Future.scala:307)
at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.$anonfun$transformWith$1(Promise.scala:41)
at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:64)
at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$AbstractBatch.processBatch(BatchingExecutor.scala:56)
at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.$anonfun$run$1(BatchingExecutor.scala:93)
at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$.withBlockContext(BlockContext.scala:85)
at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.run(BatchingExecutor.scala:93)
at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:48)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2021-04-10 06:18:36,993 [ERROR] from play.api.http.DefaultHttpErrorHandler in application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5 -

! @7jbilj46e - Internal server error, for (GET) [/v1/project/?skipN=0&limitN=10&filter=%20{}] ->

play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$$anon$1: Execution exception[[MatchError: Success(Response(MessageHeader(922, 2514918, 3001, 1), Reply(8,0,0,1), ResponseInfo(33e44ce5))) (of class scala.util.Success)]]
at play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$.throwableToUsefulException(HttpErrorHandler.scala:359)
at play.api.http.DefaultHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:261)
at play.filters.cors.AbstractCORSPolicy$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(AbstractCORSPolicy.scala:128)
at play.filters.cors.AbstractCORSPolicy$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(AbstractCORSPolicy.scala:126)
at scala.concurrent.Future.$anonfun$recoverWith$1(Future.scala:417)
at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.$anonfun$transformWith$1(Promise.scala:41)
at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:64)
at play.api.libs.streams.Execution$trampoline$.execute(Execution.scala:70)
at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:72)
at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.$anonfun$tryComplete$1(Promise.scala:288)
at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.$anonfun$tryComplete$1$adapted(Promise.scala:288)
at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:288)
at scala.concurrent.Promise.complete(Promise.scala:53)
at scala.concurrent.Promise.complete$(Promise.scala:52)
at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.complete(Promise.scala:187)
at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.$anonfun$transform$1(Promise.scala:33)
at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:64)
at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$AbstractBatch.processBatch(BatchingExecutor.scala:56)
at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.$anonfun$run$1(BatchingExecutor.scala:93)
at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$.withBlockContext(BlockContext.scala:85)
at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.run(BatchingExecutor.scala:93)
at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:48)
at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator.scala:48)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:175)
Caused by: scala.MatchError: Success(Response(MessageHeader(922, 2514918, 3001, 1), Reply(8,0,0,1), ResponseInfo(33e44ce5))) (of class scala.util.Success)
at reactivemongo.api.RetryableFailure$.unapply(Failover.scala:155)
at reactivemongo.api.Failover2.$anonfun$send$14(Failover.scala:117)
at scala.concurrent.Future.$anonfun$flatMap$1(Future.scala:307)
at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.$anonfun$transformWith$1(Promise.scala:41)
at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:64)
at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$AbstractBatch.processBatch(BatchingExecutor.scala:56)
at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.$anonfun$run$1(BatchingExecutor.scala:93)
at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$.withBlockContext(BlockContext.scala:85)
at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.run(BatchingExecutor.scala:93)
at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:48)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2021-04-10 06:18:36,998 [ERROR] from play.api.http.DefaultHttpErrorHandler in application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-7 -

! @7jbilj46i - Internal server error, for (GET) [/v1/project/count/?skipN=0&limitN=10&filter=%20{}] ->

play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$$anon$1: Execution exception[[MatchError: Success(Response(MessageHeader(922, 2514919, 3002, 1), Reply(8,0,0,1), ResponseInfo(33e44ce5))) (of class scala.util.Success)]]
at play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$.throwableToUsefulException(HttpErrorHandler.scala:359)
at play.api.http.DefaultHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:261)
at play.filters.cors.AbstractCORSPolicy$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(AbstractCORSPolicy.scala:128)
at play.filters.cors.AbstractCORSPolicy$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(AbstractCORSPolicy.scala:126)
at scala.concurrent.Future.$anonfun$recoverWith$1(Future.scala:417)
at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.$anonfun$transformWith$1(Promise.scala:41)
at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:64)
at play.api.libs.streams.Execution$trampoline$.execute(Execution.scala:70)
at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:72)
at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.$anonfun$tryComplete$1(Promise.scala:288)
at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.$anonfun$tryComplete$1$adapted(Promise.scala:288)
at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:288)
at scala.concurrent.Promise.complete(Promise.scala:53)
at scala.concurrent.Promise.complete$(Promise.scala:52)
at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.complete(Promise.scala:187)
at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.$anonfun$transform$1(Promise.scala:33)
at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:64)
at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$AbstractBatch.processBatch(BatchingExecutor.scala:56)
at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.$anonfun$run$1(BatchingExecutor.scala:93)
at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$.withBlockContext(BlockContext.scala:85)
at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.run(BatchingExecutor.scala:93)
at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:48)
at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator.scala:48)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:175)
Caused by: scala.MatchError: Success(Response(MessageHeader(922, 2514919, 3002, 1), Reply(8,0,0,1), ResponseInfo(33e44ce5))) (of class scala.util.Success)
at reactivemongo.api.RetryableFailure$.unapply(Failover.scala:155)
at reactivemongo.api.Failover2.$anonfun$send$14(Failover.scala:117)
at scala.concurrent.Future.$anonfun$flatMap$1(Future.scala:307)
at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.$anonfun$transformWith$1(Promise.scala:41)
at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:64)
at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$AbstractBatch.processBatch(BatchingExecutor.scala:56)
at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.$anonfun$run$1(BatchingExecutor.scala:93)
at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$.withBlockContext(BlockContext.scala:85)
at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.run(BatchingExecutor.scala:93)
at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:48)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Please avoid to double post questions.

Comment: Client was after us and we didn’t have any clues like why it’s behaving like this. Upgrading to 0.20.13 from 0.20.12 worked for us